# Can this line be parallel with each other?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

A ,B,C,D are four points each four different planes. If we draw all the lines between the points , can some or all of them be parallel with each other?

Comment: all of them - no (i.e. $AD$ and $BD$ will intersect), some of them - possible

Comment: Is there any proof that they could be parallel?

Comment: it's a tricky question: if there are two parallel lines that contain all 4 points, all points are on the same plane.

Comment: A proof by example would work that some *could* be parallel (*but a proof by example does not prove that they MUST be parallel*).  If you have trouble visualizing such an example... consider looking at a cube and considering the planes that contain each of the respective faces.  You could pick the points from the planes such that the points form a square.

Comment: I do not interpret this question as being that the four points must not be coplanar, just that they come from four distinct planes.  If you wish to ask the question where the four points may not be coplanar, then specify that.

Comment: @JMoravitz agreed .. though that interpretation would make the planes irrelevant. We could find four such different planes even if $A=B=C=D$

Comment: consider the case where all four points are on the same line. you can draw four distinct planes perpendicular to the line thru each point.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to project 4 parallel lines from the 4 points on the first plane to each of the other 3 planes. With no restriction on the position of the points, this is easy to visualize.

Answer (score 1):

1. Every set of 3 non-collinear points define a plane, and if there is a set of 3 co-linear points then those 3 points and the fourth define a plane (unless those 4 points are collinear that is, then there are many planes containing all 4 points). So what you (probably) mean is

> no set of 3 co-linear points, and every point not coplanar with the plane specified by the other 3 points.

2. Assuming the shaded: There are 6 lines specified here: the lines defined by $(A,B), (A,C), (A,D),(B,C), B,D)$, and $(C,D)$. Each line necessarily intersects with 4 other lines  e.g., $(A,B)$ intersects with the lines specified $(A,C),(A,D), (B,C), (B,D)$.

However, the line specified by $(A,B)$ is necessarily parallel to the line specified by $(C,D)$. Why?

> Fact 1: Let $P$ be a plane and let $L$ be a line. If $L$ is not a line in $P$ then $L$ intersects $P$ at most once.

By Fact 1, the line specified by $(C,D)$ [as $D$ is not on the plane specified by $A,B,C$] intersects the plane specified by $A,B,C$ at exactly one point, namely $C$. However, the line defined by $(A,B)$ has every point in the plane specified by $A,B,C$ so if it were to intersect the line specified by $(C,D)$, it would do so at $C$. However, the line specified by $(A,B)$ does not contain $C$ because no 3 points are collinear.

Likewise the line specified by $(A,D)$ is necessarily parallel to the line specified by $(B,C)$, and the line specified by $(A,C)$ is necessarily parallel to the line specified by $(B,D)$.

---

The argument breaks down if there is a plane containing all 4 points, in fact if $A,B,C,D$ are 4 randomly chosen points on a plane then the line specified $(A,B)$ interscts the line specified by $(C,D)$, and likewise for the other lines.